# Accessing a Method from inside Another Method

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

I was trying to access GCD from inside Algorithm but it's not letting me and I'm not sure why. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    public function gcd($x,$y) 
    {
        do {
            $rest=$x%$y;
        $x=$y;
        $y=$rest;
        } while($rest!==0);
        return $x;
    }

    public function algorithm()
    {
        $alpha = array(
            'c' => str_split('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'),
            'v' => str_split('aeiouy')
        );
        $i=$k=0;
        foreach ($this->output as $item) {
            $cnt = 0;
            $this->digits[$i] = array();
            foreach ($item as $part) {
                $this->digits[$i][$cnt] = array();
                $new = array();
                foreach ($part as $str) { 
                    $v = count(array_intersect(str_split($str), $alpha['v']));
                    $c = count(array_intersect(str_split($str), $alpha['c']));
                    $t = strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $str));

                    $new = ($cnt == 0) 
                        ? array('v' => $v, 'c' => $c, 't' => $t, 'm' => ($t%2) ? $v * 1.5 : $c) 
                        : array('v' => $v, 'c' => $c, 't' => $t);

                    $this->digits[$i][$cnt][] = $new;
                }
                $cnt++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $h=$a=0;
        foreach($this->digits as &$etc) {
            foreach($etc[0] as &$r){

                foreach($etc[1] as $k) {
                foreach($k as $x=>$y) {
                    $tmp[$h] = (gcd($y,$r['t']) != 1) ? ++$a:'';
                }
                    $tmp[$h] = $r['m']*$a*1.5;
                    $h++;
                    $a=0;
                }$h=0;

            $r['f'] = $tmp;
            $tmp='';
            }

        } 
    foreach($this->digits as &$u){unset($u[1]);}
    }
```

Comment: In order to allow for faster and better answers, it may be good to strip away as much of the irrelevant code as possible, and to clearly indicate which line causes the error.  (On top of that, it would show that you did some effort on your own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

judging by your use of the `public` identifier, I would guess your two functions are in a class.

To refer to methods on the same object, use `$this->methodname()`

from your code:

```
$tmp[$h] = (gcd($y,$r['t']) != 1) ? ++$a:'';
```

should be:

```
$tmp[$h] = ($this->gcd($y,$r['t']) != 1) ? ++$a:'';
```

Answer (score 0):

...

```
$this->gcd()?
```

But really, since `gcd` doesn't use any member variables, it should be a free function.

Comment: What do you mean a "free function"? Mind explaining it?

Comment: the plainest sort of functions - not a member-function, not a static function, not an anonymous or lambda function, just ... a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing $this->gcd inside algorithm
just tryng to acces it direct
:)